# send location details through backend channel in Bot framework

Tags: javascript, c#, botframework

I am using this method to pass location details to a bot. But as I am trying to pass an address, it is not able to fetch all details in the bot. I use alert for fulladdress variable. It shows me addresses but it's not able to get value in bot. i am try to fetch details in bot activity or event.

Can you help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // for location of user....
        var geocoder;
        var fulladdress = {};

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
        }
        //Get the latitude and the longitude;
        function successFunction(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            codeLatLng(lat, lng)
        }
        function errorFunction() {
            alert("Geocoder failed");
        }
        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        }

        function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    console.log(results)
                    if (results[1]) {
                        //formatted address
                        alert(results[0].formatted_address)
                       // fulladdress = results[0].formatted_address;
                        fulladdress = { 'latitude': results[0].formatted_address};
                        //find country name
                        for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                            for (var b = 0; b < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; b++) {

                                //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                                    //this is the object you are looking for
                                    city = results[0].address_components[i];
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //city data
                        alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name);
                        alert(fulladdress.latitude);
                           }
                    else {
                        alert("No results found");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
            });
        }


         // for Bot  .......

        var model = {
            "userId": '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
            "userName": fulladdress.latitude,
            "botId": "Chatbot Main Tree",
            "botIconUrl": "//bot-framework.azureedge.net/bot-icons-v1/bot-framework-default-8.png",
            "botName": "Chatbot Main Tree",
            "secret": "Secret",
            "iconUrl": "//bot-framework.azureedge.net/bot-icons-v1/bot-framework-default-8.png",
            "directLineUrl": "https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline",
            "webSocketEnabled": "True"
        };

        BotChat.App({
            sendTyping: true,
            user: { id: model.userId, name: model.userName },
            bot: { id: model.botId, name: model.botName },
            speechOptions: speechOptions,
            resize: 'window',
            directLine: {
                secret: model.secret,
                token: model.token,
                domain: model.directLineUrl,
                webSocket: true,
                sendTyping: true
            }
        }, document.getElementById("BotChatElement"));

            });</script>
```

Comment: Where are you sending this address to your bot? It looks like you are not posting this information

Answer (score 0):

the model and BotChat.App are used to instantiate the bot on the webpage and isn't meant for transferring data between the hosting webpage and the bot. For that, you will want to use .postActivity() and bot.on(). You can read more about setting up backchannel [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

You can see an example [here](https://github.com/BF-Support-Engineers/Location-bot) that demonstrates sending geolocation data. Look in the main.js file for .postActivity(). The example shows how to send geolocation from the browser API as well as from a service.

Hope of help!

On the webpage, event is posted following some user/page action:

```
botConnection
    .postActivity({type: "event", value: "", from: {id: "me" }, name: "buttonClicked"})
    .subscribe(id => console.log("success"));
```

In the bot, captures the posted event and acts on it:

```
bot.on("event", function (event) {
    var msg = new builder.Message().address(event.address);
    msg.data.textLocale = "en-us";
    if (event.name === "buttonClicked") {
        msg.data.text = "I see that you clicked a button.";
    }
    bot.send(msg);
})
```

Comment: there is no button click in my case i just want to pass the value that i have on my variable (js variable on html) to BOT. what will be the case now how to send the value and how can i fetch that value in bot.

Comment: and i am using c# bot sdk .

Comment: how can i convert bot.on code into c# i am using c#

Comment: Apologies. I somehow looked past your needing a c# solution. Please refer to Fei's answer above which is on target.

Answer (score 0):

> It shows me addresses but it's not able to get value in bot. i am try to fetch details in bot activity or event.

Based on your code, we can find you pass location information via `user: { id: model.userId, name: model.userName }` to initiate your BotChat, you can retrieve location information that you passed by using following code snippet.

*In bot application:*

```
var userlocation = (activity.From.Name ?? "").ToString();
```

Besides, as Steven Kanberg mentioned, you can also use the backchannel mechanism to exchange information between client and bot without presenting it to the user.

*On webpage:*

```
botConnection.postActivity({
    type: 'event',
    from: { id: model.userId },
    name: 'GetUserLocation',
    value: model.userName
}).subscribe(function (id) { console.log('UserLocation: "' + model.userName + '" sent'); });
```

*In MessagesController:*

```
private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
{
    if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
    {
        // Implement user deletion here
        // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
}

    //......
    //code logic for other messages types
//......    

else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Event && message.Name == "GetUserLocation")
    {
        var userlocation = message.Value;

        //your code logic
    }

    return null;
}
```

*Test result:*

[image]

**Note:**

[Accessing the Geocoding service is asynchronous](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding), I recommend that you can put the code snippet of assigning value to `userName` property of `model` and initating BotChat in callback function, like below.

```
function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results)
            if (results[1]) {

                //your code logic

                var model = {
                    "userId": 'user_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
                    "userName": fulladdress.latitude,
                    "botId": "Chatbot Main Tree",
                    "botIconUrl": "//bot-framework.azureedge.net/bot-icons-v1/bot-framework-default-8.png",
                    "botName": "Chatbot Main Tree",
                    "secret": "Secret",
                    "iconUrl": "//bot-framework.azureedge.net/bot-icons-v1/bot-framework-default-8.png",
                    "directLineUrl": "https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline",
                    "webSocketEnabled": "True"
                };

                var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({ secret: model.secret });

                BotChat.App({
                    directLine: botConnection,
                    user: { id: model.userId, name: model.userName },
                    //...
                    //other options
                    //...
                }, document.getElementById("BotChatElement"));

                botConnection.postActivity({
                    type: 'event',
                    from: { id: model.userId },
                    name: 'GetUserLocation',
                    value: model.userName
                }).subscribe(function (id) { console.log('UserLocation: "' + model.userName + '" sent'); });
            }
            else {
                alert("No results found");
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i don't able to get GetUserLocation in controller .. when ever code run it has property conversationUpdate not GetUserLocation . how can i solve this .

Comment: i use the method that you describe . and now the problem is that when i run the code first time my conversation type is conversationupdate and after that if i type then message .. activity type Event never run. how can i solve this i don't have any button on my html page . can you guide me how can i get activity event ?